# DataContext always ReadOnly, even though a primary key exists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm attempting to update a value in my Database, but the IsReadOnly property is always coming back as True. [According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.table-1.isreadonly?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-data-linq-table-1-isreadonly), that property

> Gets a value that indicates whether the type of the entities contained in this Table instance has a primary key

The problem is, my DB DOES have a PK set.

DB definition:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Value varchar(50) NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO TestTable (ID, Value) 
VALUES (1, '6caaef02-fc34-4112-9574-4c5923c5624d');
```

LINQ object definition:

```
[Table( Name = "TestTable" )]
public class TestTable
{
    [Column] public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The modification code:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(ConnStr);  // Just a standard SQL Server connection string
var b = db.GetTable<TestTable>().IsReadOnly;   // Always 'True'
var firstResult = db.GetTable<TestTable>().FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine( firstResult.ID + " " + firstResult.Value );  // The current DB value logs here correctly

firstResult.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
db.GetTable<TestTable>().Single(c => c.ID == 1).Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

var x = db.GetChangeSet();   // Always {{Inserts: 0, Deletes: 0, Updates: 0}}
db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
```

No exceptions are thrown, it just doesn't do anything either.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: `[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)] public int ID { get; set; }`?

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv That works! Please turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColumnAttribute` has property `IsPrimaryKey` in which indicates `PrimaryKey`. LINQ to SQL do not check database for PK while running queries. Mapping should be set by attributes.

```cs
[Table( Name = "TestTable" )]
public class TestTable
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)] public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like you're used db-first approach, and you model your entity manually.

1. if you want stay with manual modeling, try with setting `[Key]` attribute for ID property, that will indicate it's PK. - https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

   - I think there is no need to add empty `[Column]` attribute - https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx
2. Second way - try to generate model/s automatically with tool - https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/create-entity-data-model.aspx

Comment: This question is not related to EF. Before EF, LINQ To SQL was a first LINQ provider which worked only with SQL Server.